# Angular set original input field value after change

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two ng-templates.

The first one is for an input field:

```
<ng-template #tableColumnInputText let-data="data">
  <div *ngIf="!editMode[data.index][data.indexL3]" [ngClass]="{ 'enabled-text': data.state, 'disabled-text': !data.state }">{{ data.value }}</div>
  <input *ngIf="editMode[data.index][data.indexL3]" ibmText [(ngModel)]="data.value" /> // <-----
</ng-template>
```

The other one is to have an `edit` and a `cancel` functionality:

```
<ng-template #tableItemEdit let-data="data">
  <a *ngIf="!editMode[data.index][data.indexL3]" (click)="enterEditMode(data)" class="edit-icon"><svg ibmIcon="edit" size="16"></svg></a>
  <div *ngIf="editMode[data.index][data.indexL3]" class="edit-btn-group">
    <a (click)="submitEdit(data)" class="edit-icon submit-edit"><svg ibmIcon="checkmark--outline" size="20"></svg></a>
    <a (click)="cancelEdit(data)" class="edit-icon"><svg ibmIcon="close--outline" size="20"></svg></a>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

My Component is getting rendered and the input field has for example `Project 1` value initially.

With the `editMode` function I can change the input value to `Project 2` for example.

Now when I am inside the `editMode` I want to `cancel` the input field edit and want to have the original value shown again (`Project 1`).

Right now it does not work and the original value is only applied when I do a complete window refresh.

I tried it like this but it does not work unfortunately:

```
  originalValues: any;
  enterEditMode(data: any) {
    this.originalValues = data;
    this.editMode[data.index][data.indexL3] = true;
  }

  cancelEdit(data: any) {
    this.editMode[data.index][data.indexL3] = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      data.value = data.originalValues;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data = this.originalValues;`